# some questions on migrating ASP.NET 1.1 application to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, migration, .net-1.1

I need to migrate a ASP.NET application from 1.1 to 3.5. I have gone through the answers on this forum already, but still have some questions

1. should I convert the application from 1.1 to 3.5 directly? OR convert it to 2.0 first and then to 3.5 and the reasons for doing so.
2. Is there any article that walks through the whole conversion process from 1.1 to 3.5 with solutions for any typical issues encountered during the conversion process?
3. Is it possible to convert a ASP.NET 1.1 project to ASP.NET 2.0 using VS2008 OR do I need to use VS2005 IDE for doing so?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting the project from .NET 1.1 to 2 or higher, just use Visual Studio 2008.

It can convert your project to either .NET 2 or .NET 3.X, without that much hassle, and 99% of your 1.1 code will compile just fine on the new framework.

You will most likely spend way more time in converting the old code to use the new framework features, but all the 1.1 classes are still available. Therefore you can do the 'real' migration class by class; and develop new functionality using the newest framework features.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first and third questions, I have had no problems converting directly from 1.1 to 3.5 in VS2008 and I would recommend this.

Sometimes for small solutions the quickest and easiest way is to create a new .NET 3.5 solution and projects, copy your pages and controls and then merge your config files. It makes you take stock of your existing site structure as well.

Question 2: From MSDN: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pandrew/archive/2007/10/25/how-to-upgrade-from-net-framework-1-0-to-net-framework-3-5.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pandrew/how-to-upgrade-from-net-framework-1-0-to-net-framework-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

.NET 3.5 is basically an extension to .NET 2.0 so you can migrate directly to 3.5.
.NET 3.5 uses the CLR of version 2.0.

Question 2:
yes, you can use VS 2008 for doing this.